# vb.net: about catch webbrowser image link

Tags: vb.net

About catch webbrowser image link.
My webbrowser have a one image.
How can i catch this image link into TextBox?
I set the website link in wenBrowser1 Properties

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & CurElement.GetAttribute("src") & Environment.NewLine
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it on `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need?

Add a `Webbrowser` control,`2 button` controls and a `textbox` control and set textbox property to `multiline`.

When you first click on button1 you will navigate to some of your website.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
End Sub
```

And when you click button2 all the images in that weblink will be added to your textbox

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & CurElement.GetAttribute("src") & Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: can the textbox auto catch the link? no need to click the button2

Comment: @KwanMr-Yes,it can.you need to just place the button2 code inside button1 event after WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")

Comment: i mean no need to click any button:]

Comment: If you need without button click make it on form_load(or)webbrowser1_documentcompleted event.

Comment: when the pageloads make the webbrowser navigate and then it automatically displays or else I have given an alternate to it make it  on webbrowser document completed or you can give some thread.sleep to make it display as soon as it catches.

Comment: now have the error: NullReferenceException was unhandled - 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you post the entire code so that I can have a look at that.

Comment: @KwanMr-Where is the webbrowser1.navigate?that's why you're getting exception :)